# Django load specific javascript file

Tags: django

I would like to load a specific javascript file for the specific html file. Instead of loading them into the base.html. Then a lot of pages will have unnecessary scripts that are not used.

I get this error:

> Invalid block tag on line 3: 'static', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

when i try to load it into the child.html. I'm

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block js %}
    <script src="{% static "javascript/week.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `{% load static %}` in any template file that uses the `{% static %}` tag.

Comment: Something i cannot inherit from the base.html?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you inherit, you still need to explicitly load every template.

Comment: Thanks for the hrlp and explanation